# CentOS - Check partition information from command line

Tags: linux, centos

What is the command to check partition information on a CentOS 5.5 release?

Specifically, I'm looking to see if the partitions were set as LVMs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run **[`lsblk`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsblk.8.html)**. See if the “TYPE” column says `lvm`.

---

If you want more specific information:

`fdisk -l` shows the PC-style partitions on each disk.

`cat /proc/partitions` shows the available block devices. `sda`, `sdb` and so on are hard disks. `sda1` and such are partitions on these disks. `dm-0` and so on are LVM logical volumes.

`pvs` or `pvdisplay` reports the volumes that are LVM physical volumes.

`df` shows the mounted filesystems. If a filesystem is mounted from some place like `/dev/sda1`, it's not on an LVM volume. If it's mounted from `/dev/mapper/group-logical`, it's on an LVM volume.

Comment: pvs tells me the format of the partition (it shows LVM2). Tanxsomuch!

Comment: Just a quick "sanity check" - I assume this is still correct/current as of CentOS 7?  (and/or most current Linux dists)

Comment: @JoelAZ That hasn't changed, but there's now a tool that makes it much easier: `lsblk`.

Answer (score 0):

Running `pvdisplay` will show you information about the various known PVs. `pvscan` will scan the current devices for PVs.